# window.location.replace is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ajax post that I need to redirect to redirect url on success.
In the browser debugger I do c the correct url but I'm always getting "MYURL/undefined".

```js
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/NewsLetter/Create",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data: data,

        success: function(result) { //debug >result={urlOne:'https://localhost:7077'}
            //  alert('Successfully received Data ');

            if (result.UrlOne !== undefined) {
                window.location.replace(result.UrlOne);
            } else {
                window.location.replace(result.UrlTwo);
            }
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert('Failed to receive the Data');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('Failed ');
        }
    });
```

In my controller:

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid && isNewUser == null)
{
   //remove for clear code
    return Json(new { UrlOne = Url.ActionLink("Index","Home")});
}

TempData["ErrorMes"] = "You are allready register";
return Json(new { UrlTwo = Url.ActionLink("_RegNews", "NewsLetter") });
```

Comment: Have you checked what the values of `result.urlOne` and `result.urlTwo` are?

Comment: if i understand your Q.  then yes this are 2 valid url

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how ever  window.location.replace('https://localhost:7077'); is also undefined" while paste it in the browser is a valid Url

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive, you use `urlOne` and `UrlOne` - they are not the same.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `JsonSerializerOptions` as a parameter when creating the `Json` object to make property's name case-sensitive during deserialization. The `JsonSerializerOptions` has `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` property that by default set to `false`. This will prevent the Json serializer to change names to be camel-cased.

```cs
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();

if (ModelState.IsValid && isNewUser == null)
{
   //remove for clear code
    return Json(new { UrlOne = Url.ActionLink("Index","Home")}, options);
}

TempData["ErrorMes"] = "You are allready register";
return Json(new { UrlTwo = Url.ActionLink("_RegNews", "NewsLetter") }, options);
```

[JsonSerializerOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the return json from controller:

[image]

You will find that the key is `urlOne` instead of `UrlOne`.

Javascript is case sensitive, So you need to change your code like:

```
if (result.urlOne !== undefined) {
                    window.location.replace(result.urlOne);
                } else {
                    window.location.replace(result.urlTwo);
                }
```